# Will one bad address stop delivery to good address when sending to multiple addresses via Mailgun

Tags: email, mailgun

I am sending emails from a webapp using Javascript->Firebase->Zapier->Mailgun. That works. I want to send the same (not customized for each recipient) email to 2 or 3 addresses. I am trying to decide if I should send multiple emails or send one email with multiple addresses (separated by commas) in the "to:" field.

1) If I send one email to multiple email addresses, will one bad email address (properly formatted, but not deliverable) prevent the other email addresses from receiving the email?

2) Would the answer be different if I used the multiple email addresses in the "bcc:" field?

3) Lastly, if one bad email address does NOT prevent delivery to the good addresses, is there a performance reason to choose between sending multiple emails or sending one with multiple addresses in the "to:" or "bcc:" field? (I'm not so worried about a few seconds or minutes delay for my non-time-critical emails, I'm more concerned about about being a good citizen with Mailgun, as I'm a free-tier user.)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Isn't this a question for Mailgun support?

Comment: Surely you can experiment on the first two using some email addresses of your own or in your company?